# Can a generic lambda have no arguments?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

First of all, I know I could use templated class/functor, but that is not what I want.

Here is the lambda:

```
auto lambda = [] (auto var) {
    decltype(var) x;

    //do stuff with x but nothing with var
};
```

The problem is I receive the warning C4100(unreferenced formal parameter). I also know I could use tricks such as disabling the warning and enabling it again after the lambda or using macros such as UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER, but that is cheating.

Is there any way I could accomplish that?

An ideal code would look like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto lambda = [] () {
    T x;

    //do stuff with x
};
```

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using MSVC 2015 RC.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use var, since it has been passed to you by value, so it is already your own local copy of the variable. Immediately declaring another like it seems redundant. Specifically, `var` is `auto` so it lost any reference properties etc, while `x` is `decltype(var)`.

Comment: OK - I see it now - I read your first line as saying you didn't want to use templates. But your ideal code is a template, so I guess it's just the functor/class you wanted to avoid, sorry.

Comment: The real lambda in my code is different and I actually don't create a variable, but I use decltype to access static members of a class.

Comment: You can also just say `auto lambda = [] (auto _) { (void)(&_); /* your code */ };`.

Comment: That was pointed out by @Barry , but that is considered cheating since UNREFERENCED_PARAMATER macro does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact, in C++14 you can create "template lambdas" using exactly the syntax you want, but only in namespace scope:

```
// (1)
template <typename T>
auto l = [] () {
    T x;
};

int main() {
    l<int>();
}
```

It's not a generic lambda, it's a variable template, but you can even create generic template lambda:

```
template <typename T>
auto l = [] (auto y) {
    T x = 42;
    std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64437ee93fd16458)

But there is a downside: it seems that among current compilers only Clang supports this.

**Update**: Since this can only be done in namespace scope, if your lambda has no arguments, or doesn't have `auto` arguments (that is, it's not generic), it can be replaced by a function without requiring even any C++11 features, not mentioning C++14. If such lambda has captures, they can capture only global variables, so the corresponding function may just use the same variables or their copies. Thanks to @JasonR for pointing this out:

```
// effectively the same as (1)
template <typename T>
void l() {
    T x;
}
```

Comment: @user2565020 I don't think it will help you, because VS2015 [doesn't support variable templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx). I added this answer just for completeness.

Comment: Agreed, but my code can wait 2 or 3 years to be complete.

Comment: Since this can only be used at namespace scope, does this provide any features that a plain function template doesn't? Seems like you could accomplish the same thing without C++14 by making `l` a function template instead of a lambda, as the lambda doesn't seem to be buying you anything here.

Comment: Can you explain (with standard references) why this is valid instead of being an error like GCC 5 gives?

Comment: @JasonR In the first case it seems you are right. In the second case you can have say `l<int>` and pass it to some generic algorithm, but you won't be able to do the same with a function.

Comment: plus one from me, first time I'm seeing a templated variable used this way.

Answer (score 10):

If you really don't need the argument, just wrap it in `void`:

```
auto lambda = [](auto var) {
    (void)var; // now we used it - more or less
    decltype(var) x;
    /* whatever else */
};
```

Comment: Not a lovely modern solution but that's because one doesn't exist (aside from using the correct tools for the job). +1

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER do, but thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 7):

Do not use lambda:

```
template<typename T>
struct Functor
{
   void operator () () { T var; ... }
}
```

A lambda is nothing else, a compiler generated functor.

Comment: @user2565020: Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

This is not what lambdas are for, and there is no syntax to do it (aside from hacking away the warning).

Just write a proper function template. Not everything has to be a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

No, a generic lambda cannot have no arguments because it doesn't have arguments to deduce a type from. You will have to use the fallback templated functor.